# Django Override Default Save add ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has a many to many relationship to another model.
I am trying to update the many to many relationship on save, but nothing is being added.

Creating a new Flight via the Python Interpreter, saving it, and then running the loop I have in the 'save' method adds the correct lanes to the many to many relationship.

What am I missing in the overridden save method?

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    number_of_lanes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    lanes = models.ManyToManyField(Lane, blank=True)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey('Tournament')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Lanes: %s | Start: %s' % (self.number_of_lanes, self.start_time)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Flight, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(1, self.number_of_lanes+1):
            lane = Lane.objects.get(id=i)
            self.lanes.add(lane)
```

Here is the Console snippet from where I tested it:

```
>>> flight = Flight()
>>> flight.number_of_lanes=5
>>> flight.start_time='8:30'
>>> flight.tournament=t
>>> flight.save()
>>> flight.lanes.all()
[<Lane: 1>, <Lane: 2>, <Lane: 3>, <Lane: 4>, <Lane: 5>]
```

Edit:
Brief update on where I am on this.

The save method works within the console. The first time I tested it, I forgot to reload the Django shell. The many to many relationship is still not being created when adding from the admin page.
If the overridden save method works within the shell, shouldn't it work on the Django admin page?

Comment: I would suspect that although you are adding lanes to the Flight, you are actually setting number_of_lanes to 0. Can you add a snippet with the full example you are testing with? Perhaps there lies the mistake.

Comment: @Sebastian even if number_of_lanes is 0, he is adding +1

Comment: @Gocht yup. range(1,1) is an empty set. I don't see an error in the looping code, that's why I would suspect the test.

Comment: @Sebastian He's starting at 1, I didn't see. Try testing when you are sure that number_of_lanes > 0

Comment: @Gocht I've tried testing with a hard-coded value larger than 0 in the range, but the many to many fields are still not added during the save method.

Comment: Are you sure this line -> lane = Lane.objects.get(id=i) is getting a Lane object?

Comment: Yes, because if it were not then the insert would fail.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [the following article](http://timonweb.com/posts/many-to-many-field-save-method-and-the-django-admin/). It basically describes that when you save a model through the admin forms, it isn't an atomic transaction.

> The main object is saved first, then the M2M is cleared and the new
>   values set to whatever came out of the form. So if you are in the
>   save() of the main object you are in a window of opportunity where the
>   M2M hasn't been updated yet. In fact, if you try to do something to
>   the M2M, the change will get wiped out by the clear().